# Visual Studio 2012 - Turn off live error checking - Typescript

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2012 and when I have to refactor my code and must temporarily introduce a lot of errors visual studio become unresponsive for up to a minute, very often, making it impossible to refactor efficiently.

How can I turn this off temporarily until I feel like I've patched the majority of errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be that bad, else it's a bug.  Unfortunately with the latest release there is an issue being investigated.  See https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/779 .  If it's not this issue, then please log another describing how to reproduce the issue you are seeing reliably, and it will get investigated.

There is a fix checked in for the above issue that is being tested currently (see https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/e44dbae94e04 ).  If you are feeling lucky and don't want to wait for the next update, you could always replace this line of code yourself in the typescriptServices.js file and see if it resolves your issue.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/29/trying-the-latest-typescript-build.aspx for details on the location of the file to update.

Comment: I was consistently having issues with typescript hanging my VS 2012 instance.  I added this code in my typescriptService.js `
                while(node && node.Kind !== Formatting.AuthorParseNodeKind.apnkEmpty && node.Kind !== Formatting.AuthorParseNodeKind.apnkEmptyNode && node.nodeType !== TypeScript.NodeType.List) {`.  You can reference the link @Bill referenced above [see codeplex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/e44dbae94e04).